# How to deal with WSDL complexType on Android app development?

Tags: java, android, web-services, complextype

I am using Eclipse Indigo to create an Android application to invoke a webservice. This is already working on a Java project but I know this is a whole different thing.

I know you can use ksoap2 library and invoke the webservice like this:

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
request.addProperty("something","Somevalue");
```

But I don't know how to invoke the webservice when your WSDL is of complexType, like the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<definitions name='Gator' targetNamespace='http://home.com/gatorws/ws/Gator/' xmlns='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/' xmlns:tns='http://home.com/gatorws/ws/Gator/' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
 <types>
  <xs:schema targetNamespace='http://home.com/gatorws/ws/Gator/' version='1.0' xmlns:tns='http://home.com/gatorws/ws/Gator/' xmlns:xs='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>
   <xs:element name='Gator'>
    <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name='idBus' type='tns:IdBusCT'/>
      <xs:element name='infoGPS' type='tns:InfoGPSCT'/>
      <xs:element name='infoBus' type='tns:InfoBusCT'/>
      <xs:element name='infoMore' type='tns:InfoMoreCT'/>
      <xs:element maxOccurs='unbounded' minOccurs='0' name='msjcs' nillable='true' type='tns:Mesaje'/>
      <xs:element name='msjOPT' type='tns:MsjCor'/>
     </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name='GatorFault'>
    <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name='result' type='xs:int'/>
      <xs:element name='msj' type='xs:string'/>
     </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:element name='GatorResponse'>
    <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name='result' type='tns:Result'/>
     </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
   <xs:complexType name='IdBusCT'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name='idOp' type='xs:int'/>
     <xs:element name='codBus' nillable='true' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element name='codEqu' nillable='true' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element name='codType' type='xs:int'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='InfoGPSCT'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name='lat' type='xs:double'/>
     <xs:element name='lng' type='xs:double'/>
     <xs:element name='date' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element name='direction' type='xs:int'/>
     <xs:element name='valid' type='xs:int'/>
     <xs:element name='velocity' type='xs:double'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='InfoBusCT'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element default='1' name='ignition' nillable='true' type='xs:int'/>
     <xs:element default='0' name='emergency' nillable='true' type='xs:int'/>
     <xs:element default='0' name='idRoute' nillable='true' type='xs:int'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='MsjCor'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name='last' type='xs:lng'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='InfoMoreCT'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element default='' name='CODDriver' nillable='true' type='xs:string'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='Result'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name='result' type='xs:int'/>
     <xs:element maxOccurs='unbounded' minOccurs='0' name='msjOPT' nillable='true' type='tns:Mesaje'/>
     <xs:element name='msjcs' nillable='true' type='tns:MsjCor'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
   <xs:complexType name='Mesaje'>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element name='type' type='xs:int'/>
     <xs:element name='text' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element name='date' type='xs:string'/>
     <xs:element name='corr' type='xs:int'/>
    </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
  </xs:schema>
 </types>
 <message name='Gator_Gator'>
  <part element='tns:Gator' name='Gator'></part>
 </message>
 <message name='Gator_GatorResponse'>
  <part element='tns:GatorResponse' name='GatorResponse'></part>
 </message>
 <message name='GatorFault'>
  <part element='tns:GatorFault' name='GatorFault'></part>
 </message>
 <portType name='Gator'>
  <operation name='Gator' parameterOrder='Gator'>
   <input message='tns:Gator_Gator'></input>
   <output message='tns:Gator_GatorResponse'></output>
   <fault message='tns:GatorFault' name='GatorFault'></fault>
  </operation>
 </portType>
 <binding name='GatorBinding' type='tns:Gator'>
  <soap:binding style='document' transport='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http'/>
  <operation name='Gator'>
   <soap:operation soapAction='http://home.com/gatorws/ws/Gator/Gator'/>
   <input>
    <soap:body use='literal'/>
   </input>
   <output>
    <soap:body use='literal'/>
   </output>
   <fault name='GatorFault'>
    <soap:fault name='GatorFault' use='literal'/>
   </fault>
  </operation>
 </binding>
 <service name='Gator'>
  <port binding='tns:GatorBinding' name='GatorImplPort'>
   <soap:address location='https://10.0.2.2:8080/gatoryws/Gator?wsdl'/>
  </port>
 </service>
</definitions>
```

I am just being able to get a fail answer from the webservice.

I tried http://www.wsdl2code.com but that's for .NET webservices.

I also tried http://easywsdl.com/ but I don't understand how it works in my case.

Is there another tool that I could use?
Should I migrate to Android Studio?

Comment: If you're wondering if Android Studio will help your web request completely successfully you should go read up on the protocol you're trying to use. http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_soap.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this, it was really helpful:
http://binarylifebyanjula.blogspot.cl/2013/11/android-webservices-ksoap2-complex.html

Here I'm going to tell you how to retrieve a complex type object. I created the ComplexTypeActivity for this. For the UI I just added a button and a text view to display results. Let's create the complex type class.
Here I created a class which contain 3 string values. I named it as SimpleObject.

```
public class SimpleObject implements KvmSerializable {

 private String name;
 private String address;
 private String id;

 public String getId() {
  return id;
 }

 public void setId(String id) {
  this.id = id;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public String getAddress() {
  return address;
 }

 public void setAddress(String address) {
  this.address = address;
 }

 @Override
 public Object getProperty(int pid) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  switch (pid) {
  case 0:
   return this.id;

  case 1:
   return this.name;

  case 2:
   return this.address;

  default:
   break;

  }

  return null;
 }

 @Override
 public int getPropertyCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return 3;
 }

 @Override
 public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable htable, PropertyInfo info)                  {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  switch (index) {
  case 0:
   info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
   info.name = "id";
   break;
  case 1:
   info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
   info.name = "name";
   break;
  case 2:
   info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
   info.name = "address";
   break;

  }

 }

 @Override
 public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  switch (index) {
  case 0:
   this.id = value.toString();
   break;
  case 1:
   this.name = value.toString();
   break;
  case 2:
   this.address = value.toString();
   break;

  }

 }

}
```

Note that I implemented the KvmSerializable interface here. Using that interface KSOAP map those class properties with soap message.

Same as earlier I'm going to call the web service when pressed the button.

```
btnShowDetails.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
   LoadDetailsTask task = new LoadDetailsTask();
  task.execute("ID01");
 }
 });


class LoadDetailsTask extends AsyncTask<string simpleobject="" void=""> {

  private final String NAMESPACE = "http://service.blog.anjula.com/";
  private final String URL = "http://112.135.137.22:8080/BlogWebService/BlogWebService?WSDL";
  private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://service.blog.anjula.com/getDetails";
  private final String METHOD_NAME = "getDetails";

  SimpleObject result = new SimpleObject();

  @Override
  protected SimpleObject doInBackground(String... addId) {

   SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

   PropertyInfo idListPropety = new PropertyInfo();

   idListPropety.setName("id");
   idListPropety.setValue(addId[0]);
   idListPropety.setType(addId[0].getClass());
   request.addProperty(idListPropety);

   SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
     SoapEnvelope.VER11);

   // envelope.dotNet = true;
   envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

   envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "SimpleObject",
     new SimpleObject().getClass());

   HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

   try {
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
    SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

    result.setId(response.getProperty("id").toString());
    result.setName(response.getProperty("name").toString());
    result.setAddress(response.getProperty("address").toString());

    return result;

   } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

   return null;

  }

  @Override
  protected void onPostExecute(SimpleObject result) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if (result != null)
    textViewResult.setText("Id: " + result.getId() + "\nName: "
      + result.getName() + "\nAddress: "
      + result.getAddress());
  }

 }
```

Here you can see I'm mapping the out put using field names.

```
result.setId(response.getProperty("id").toString());
    result.setName(response.getProperty("name").toString());
    result.setAddress(response.getProperty("address").toString());
```

In URL I entered my IP address there, because I ran the service in my computer. Therefore you have to change that IP address to your IP address if you're running the server application in your computer.
After you pressed the button the program will invoke this method.

```
public SimpleObject getDetails(String id){
        SimpleObject result = new SimpleObject();        
        result.setId(id);
        result.setName("Anjula");
        result.setAddress("Kaduwela");        
        return result;        
    }
```

That's all :D